# Dynamically put and remove a item from numpy array at a constant rate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time

I want to put and delete a certain item in a numpy array dynamically, that is, with timing.

This is my current code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

gen_array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0]])

insert_candidate = np.array([1])
counter = 0
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(1):
        np.put(gen_array[i + counter], range(1, 2), insert_candidate)
    print(gen_array)
    print('\n')
    counter += 1
```

Albeit it's adding an item to the next row every second, it's keeping the old one.

Is there any function that deals with this or possible solution?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert ?

Comment: That doesn't help, sorry

Comment: ok sorry I think what you want to do is unclear for me : you ant to insert a new row each second or delete? what are the condition for the new row being added or deleted ?

Comment: Basically, once a new item is inserted, the previous one has to be deleted, that is, reverted to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what you want but ...

May be you want something like :

```
import time
import numpy as np

gen_array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0]])

insert_candidate = np.array([1])
counter = 0
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    gen_array[counter][1]=1
    gen_array[counter-1][1]=0
    print(gen_array)
    print('\n')
    counter += 1
```

Comment: It's an array, you can index with `gen_array[counter,1]`.

Comment: Tried this already. It's efficient if you're trying to insert only one item, but it's another story if the item is complex, like a Tetris piece.

Comment: Setting the old slot(s) to 0 is no more complex than setting the new one(s) to 1.  I could suggest a whole array `fill`, but the wouldn't distinguish between the 'piece' you are moving, and old pieces.  `numpy` indexing is not optimized for this kind of action.

Comment: @Cast Fellow, if your doing a tetris game, you can think in an other architecture, like in this example : https://gist.github.com/silvasur/565419

Comment: @CastFellow It's maybe easier to keep the value of the postion (x,y) in the array until than make the piece move inside the array, or you can create 2 array one to keep the postions and the other to "display"